# Is there a purpose for using a macro that does nothing over an empty macro in c++?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

Learning c++ and reading through a project, I found this.

```
#define EMPTY_MACRO do {} while (0)

...

#if ASSERTS_ENABLED
#define ASSERTCORE(expr) assert(expr)
#else
#define ASSERTCORE(expr) EMPTY_MACRO
#endif
```

What is the purpose of `EMPTY_MACRO`? Is it unnecessary or is there a reason for it?

Comment: One consequence would be that if you did `#define EMPTY_MACRO` to make it just nothing, then you could place `ASSERTCORE` in places where it's not actually syntactically valid to place an assertion and you wouldn't realize anything was wrong until you turned `ASSERTS_ENABLED` on.

Comment: The `do{}while(0)` will play nice with the trailing semicolon from `ASSERTCORE(true);`

Comment: For example of the kind of thing I mean: [See here](https://godbolt.org/z/odMrYnxbo). If `EMPTY_MACRO` is an entire little trivial do-while loop, then it refuses to compile even if I haven't set `ASSERTS_ENABLED`. But if I just make `EMPTY_MACRO` empty, then it happily lets me place the macro where it doesn't belong.

Comment: by the way, none of this is C++, inherently. On the contrary, this is a very C, and a very un-C++-like way of solving the problem of compile-time disabling assertions.

Comment: Therefore: If you're learning C++, the code you're looking through is *probably* not a good example!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's there so

```
ASSERTCORE(expr);
```

behaves the same with or without ASSERTS_ENABLED. A plain `#define ASSERTCORE(expr)` would leave behind a lone `;` and that would behave differently in some cases.